# Selenium WebDrive findElements return object

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I'm trying to loop over some table and get the innerHTML() but when I try to do it I get innerHTML is not a function.
I've looked over the documentation and findElements should return an array but if I check the type of item is an object

```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

    driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/');

    driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="question-mini-list"]/div'))
    .then(function(item) {
        console.log( item );
    });
```

Comment: I suppose that your question is how do you get all the elements? btw please provide the html too (or just a small example)

Comment: you need to actually specify that you want the text use the method .getText()

Comment: In Java `findElements` returns a list of WebElements. It's strange to receive something different here. Can you try with cssSelector `By.cssselector('#question-mini-lust > div'`? Just to check if it changes the result...

Comment: @redp Ok , how I can do that?

Comment: `driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="question-mini-list"]/div')).getText()
    .then(function(item) {
        console.log( item );`

Comment: does that work??

Comment: @redp No, I get driver.findElements(...).getText() is not a function

Comment: @Tom I've tried but I get the same thing . I got the css selector from doc. http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/selenium-core/lib/prototype.js#L1346), `findElements` returns an `Array`, which contains `Elements` (objects!).

```
findElements: function(scope) {
  var element;

  if (element = $(this.params.id))
    if (this.match(element))
      if (!scope || Element.childOf(element, scope))
        return [element];

  scope = (scope || document).getElementsByTagName(this.params.tagName || '*');

  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < scope.length; i++)
    if (this.match(element = scope[i]))
      results.push(Element.extend(element));

  return results;
}
```

To get the innerHTML, you can use the `getAttribute` function on the element:

```
item[0].getAttribute('innerHTML');
```